# Two commands in one line, end both when either ends

Tags: ruby, linux, unix

I'm trying to write a bash script (for linux) that will start two processes at the same time -- a GUI and a background process -- and will exit both if either exits. There's plenty of documentation about starting both at once (the & ampersand is easy enough), but the exit of one does not cause the other to exit. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

For extra info: I'm starting two ruby programs. I'm working on ubuntu. It's for a kiosk.

Comment: So if one process terminates, you want to automatically terminate the other?

Comment: Do the processes exit cleanly, or do you want to catch it even if they go down in flames?

Answer (score 3):

I've used *[sleep(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep)* as an example; replace each sleep with a ruby launch...

```
(sleep 5
 kill 0)&
(sleep 10
 kill 0)&
wait
```